# understanding the stack

Tags: ida, assembly, x86

I have de-assembled a x86 application use ida, it generates
the following code

```
.text:1084FF10                 push    ebp
.text:1084FF11                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:1084FF13                 and     esp, 0FFFFFFF8h
.text:1084FF16                 sub     esp, 0D4h
.text:1084FF1C                 mov     eax, ___security_cookie
.text:1084FF21                 xor     eax, esp
```

What does the instruction "and esp, 0FFFFFFF8h" do here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This aligns the stack pointer to 8 byte boundary. This is done by the compiler to improve performance, as reads from non-aligned addresses results in performance degradation.